# object convert to json how to modify the property key?

Tags: json, jackson

i have a json like

> ```
> "weatherInfo":{
>             "city":"北京",
>             "publishDate":"2014年3月4日",
>             "week":"星期二",
>             "tempRange":"8℃~-3℃",
>             "feelTemp":"10",
>             "time":"16:05",
>             "temp":"11",
>             "WD":"北风",
>             "WS":"2级",
>             "SD":"27%",                      
>             "weather1":"晴"
>           }
> ```

and my class is

```
public class WeatherVO implements Serializable{

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 2348480036959754071L;

    @JsonProperty(value="weatherinfo")
    private WeatherInfoVO weatherInfoVO;
    @JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown=true)
    public class WeatherInfoVO{
        //城市
        @JsonProperty(value="city")
        private String city;
        //发布日期
        private String publishDate;
        //发布时间
        @JsonProperty(value="time")
        private String publishTime;
        //星期
        private String week;
        //温度范围
        private String tempRange;
        //当前时刻温度
        @JsonProperty(value="temp")
        private String currentTemp;
        //风向
        @JsonProperty(value="WD")
        private String windDirection;
        //风力
        @JsonProperty(value="WS")
        private String windForce;
        //当前时刻湿度
        @JsonProperty(value="SD")
        private String currentHumidity;
        //体感温度
        private String feelTemp;

        //天气描述
        private String weatherDesc;
   }
}
```

i want to convert json to object like:

```
WeatherVO weatherVO = objectMapper.readValue (jsonString, WeatherVO.class);
```

and i want to return json use org.springframework.http.converter.json.MappingJacksonHttpMessageConverter class
and the return json is

> "weatherInfo":{
>               "city":"北京",
>               "publishDate":"2014年3月4日",
>               "week":"星期二",
>               "tempRange":"8℃~-3℃",
>               "feelTemp":"10",
>               "time":"16:05",
>               "temp":"11",
>               "WD":"北风",
>               "WS":"2级",
>               "SD":"27%",
>               "weather1":"晴"
>             }

but i want to return like

> "weatherInfo":{
>               "city":"北京",
>               "publishDate":"2014年3月4日",
>               "week":"星期二",
>               "tempRange":"8℃~-3℃",
>               "feelTemp":"10",
>               "publishTime":"16:05",
>               "currentTemp":"11",
>               "windDirection":"北风",
>               "windForce":"2级",
>               "currentHumidity":"27%",
>               "weather":"晴"
>             }

how can i do that?
thanks for your any suggestion and help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve this by marking the getter of the field by @JsonIgnore then create another method that get the field and mark it as @JsonProperty. 
My advice is to rename first your fields to avoid confusion. I renamed it like the json you have. So for example.

```
  public class WeatherInfoVO{

       private String city;
       private String publishDate;
       private String week;
       private String tempRange;
       private String feelTemp;
       private String time;
       private String temp;
       private String WD;
       private String WS;
       private String SD;
       private String weather1;
      //getters and setters

    }
```

then in you setters method mark the appropriate @JsonProperty.

```
    @JsonProperty(value="time")
    public void setTime(String time) {
     this.temp = temp;
    }

    @JsonProperty(value="temp")
    public void setTemp(String temp) {
        this.temp = temp;
    }

    @JsonProperty(value="WD")
    public void setWD(String WD) {
        this.WD = WD;
    }   

    @JsonProperty(value="WS")
    public void setWS(String WS) {
        this.WS = WS;
    }
    @JsonProperty(value="SD")
    public void setSD(String SD) {
        this.SD = SD;
    }
    @JsonProperty(value="weather1")
    public void setWeather1(String weather1) {
        this.weather1 = weather1;
    }
    //other setters here
```

and in your getters, make sure to add @JsonIgnore to the fields you want to rename. Since you declare it as @JsonIgnore, you need to create another getter and mark it as @JsonProperty. Do it only to the fields you are going to rename, in your case the fields are time, temp, WD, WS, SD and weather1 only. Here's an example.

```
    @JsonIgnore
    public void getTime(){
     return time;
    }

    @JsonProperty(value="publishTime")
    public void getPublishTime(){
     return time;
    }

    @JsonIgnore
    public void getTemp(){
     return temp;
    }
    @JsonProperty(value="currentTemp")
    public void getCurrentTemp(){
     return temp;
    }

    @JsonIgnore
    public void getWD(){
     return WD;
    }

    @JsonProperty(value="windDirection")
    public void getWindDirection(){
     return WD;
    }

    @JsonIgnore
    public void getWS(){
     return WS;
    }

    @JsonProperty(value="windForce")
    public void getWindForce(){
     return WS;
    }

    @JsonIgnore
    public void getSD(){
     return SD;
    }

    @JsonProperty(value="currentHumidity")
    public void getCurrentHumidity(){
     return SD;
    }

    @JsonIgnore
    public void getWeather1(){
     return weather1;
    }

    @JsonProperty(value="weather")
    public void getWeather(){
     return weather1;
    }
```